# jquery AJAX pulls data from XML - last 4 items only

Tags: ajax, arrays, jquery

I am working on a sort of aggregator/tweet wall. At the mo it only uses data from an XML file (of our latest news). I made a bit of a mistake in the logic, though.

At present it only pulls items from the last 30 days. [**Live demo**](http://www.sagittarius-digital.com/sag-aggregator/sag-aggregator.html) takes a few secs to load (using last 240 days for extra content to work with). However, I need it to:

- Pull the last 4 items in chrono order.
- Shuffle that array so they are
  random ordered (but will all be "fresh" news).
- Output that array.

> ```
> jQuery(function () {
>     $.ajax({
>         url: 'http://www.sagittarius-digital.com/news.rss',
>         dataType: 'xml',
>         complete: function() {
>           /*Init masonry.js*/
>           var container = document.querySelector('#container');
>           var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
>               // options
>               gutter: 20,
>               columnWidth: 320,
>               itemSelector: '.item'
>             });
>           }
>     }).done(function (xml) {
>         var items = [];
>         $(xml).find('item').each(function () {
>             var $item    = $(this);
>             var date     = new Date($item.find('pubDate').text());
>             var date_30  = new Date().getTime() - (1000*60*60*24*240); /* last figure = number of days to sort back from */
>             var yyyymmdd = date.getFullYear() + '' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '' + date.getDate();
>
>             if ( date_30 < date.getTime() ) { // newer than 30 days
>                 var array = '<div class="item"><h2>News</h2>';
>                 array += '<p>' + yyyymmdd + '</p>';
>                 array += '<a href="' + $item.find('link').text() + '">';
>                 array += '<h2>' + $item.find('title').text() + '</h2>';
>                 array += '<p>' + $item.find('description').text() + '</p>';>     
>
>                 array += '<p>Category: ' + $item.find('category').text() + '</p>';
>                 array += '</a>';
>                 array += '</div>';
>                 items.push(array);
>             }
>         });
>         $('div.item').after(items.join(' '));
>     }).fail(function () {
>         console.log('error', arguments)
>     });
> });
> ```

Basically after that I need to add a second RSS feed with different info doing the same, a Twitter ajax call and facebook ajax call. So I will have 12 bits of data that are all the 4 "freshest", these will then shuffle into a random order and output, so there is a nice even mix.

Comment: Why not just use `.done()` `.fail()` and `.always()` instead of including just one callback as a setting (`complete`)?

Comment: you need last four items from xml or latest 4 items in random order ?

Comment: Last four from XML into sub-array, then reshuffled

Comment: try something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/E6hMe/1/